# How to read from an existing .txt file without hard coding (winforms)?

Tags: c#, winforms, path, hardcode

I am working on a project with winforms. I want to read from an existing .txt file but without hard coding. This means that I want to allow the user to provide the path of the file as input. I have tried the following code:

```
private void pathSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = "";
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        path = ofd.FileName;
        pathSearch.Text = File.ReadAllText(path);
    }

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        // Create a file to write to.
        string[] createText = { "Hello", "And", "Welcome" };
        File.WriteAllLines(path, createText);
    }

    string[] values;

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        values = lines[i].ToString().Split('|');
        string[] row = new string[values.Length];

        for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
        {
            row[j] = values[j].Trim();
        }
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

You can check [screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOanS.png) and [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hInPy.png) to give you an idea of how it will work. I want to enter the path inside the text field but it gives me an ArgumentNullException. After entering the path I want to import by using the button to see the data on that table. 
P.s I'm not sure if checking the existence of the path, works that way.

**Edit**
  After the comments I edited my code and I have something that works. However, in order to import the file I have to select it 2 times and it is writing the same lines [twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGSqd.png) inside the table. How can I fix that?

Comment: This is not a Console application; `string path = Console.ReadLine();` won't help. Use the `Button.Click` event, not the `TextBox.TextChanged` event. You'ld need the `pathSearch.Text` property value. Use the `OpenFileDialog` class to create a standard open dialog to select a file. `File.Exists(path) => ` this condition will be verified in the OpenFileDialog. But, if you check that out yourself, do it before `File.ReadAllLines(path);`, otherwise it's quite useless. etc.

Comment: [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline) reads input from the console window. You need to use the text from your `TextBox` instead. Or better yet, implement a [`OpenFileDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog)

Comment: You edit the `Text` property of `pathsearch` inside the `TextChanged` method, which will trigger this event again.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're doing this in the `TextChanged` event of the `pathSearch` text box, and you're modifying the text inside that event, so the event gets fired twice:

```
// This line of code causes the pathSearch_TextChanged event to fire again
pathSearch.Text = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

***As a side note: do you really mean to write the contents of the file to the `Text` property of `pathSearch`, or should it just be the `FileName` instead?***

---

Probably the best solution is to not modify the contents of a control inside an event that gets triggered when the contents are modified. Normally the `OpenFileDialog` is launched from a `Button_Click` event:

```
// Launch the file browser dialog from the click event of the Import button
private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;

    var path = ofd.FileName;
    pathSearch.Text = path;

    // Code continues...
}
```